# Is OAuth 2.0 redundant/unnecessary if the client is the same as the resource owner?

Tags: api, oauth

In section [1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1) of RFC 6749, there are four roles: resource owner, resource server, client, and authorization server.

Does OAuth become redundant or unnecessary if the client and the resource owner are the same entity?

For example, I have a closed API and a front-facing web server. (The front-facing web server would be both the client and the resource owner.) I am trying to decide whether to switch to OAuth 2 authentication instead of using the current username/password authentication method. Is there any added security for moving to OAuth 2 if the API remains closed to third-party applications? (That is, no third-parties will ever have access to the API.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where the Resource Owner and Client/Resource Server roles coincide OAuth 2.0 may become less relevant from a security point of view, since one of the primary objectives of OAuth not to expose primary credentials of the user to the client becomes moot. That is also the reason why the so-called Resource Owner Password Credentials grant is considered to be a legacy/deprecated flow.

However, it may still make sense to follow the OAuth 2.0 pattern for a number of reasons:

- the ability to leverage a standardized protocol through stock libraries and
  frameworks without relying on custom code
- the fact that in your case the Resource Server is still made strictly OAuth 2.0 compliant, dealing with Clients presenting access tokens, irrespective of what the Client/Resource Owner relationship/implementation is; this would make it easier to allow for 3rd-party client access in a future scenario
- the fact that you concentrate verification of user credentials on a single path between Client and Authorization Server so each of your Resource Servers don't need to be bothered by checking user credentials individually, possibly dealing with different authentication mechanisms
- and perhaps most importantly, also security-wise: once the user has authenticated through the Client using his primary credentials, the Authorization Server can issue a refresh token as well as an access token; the Client can store and use the refresh token to a new access token when the old one expires; this frees the Client from storing the primary user credentials if it wants to keep accessing the API for a long period of time without requiring explicit user interaction and authentication and makes the resulting system less vulnerable for leakage/loss of user credentials since the user credentials (password) are not stored in the Clients

Comment: Thanks! Just looking for some discussion. I really appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following issue then you should use OAuth;

Let's say you a Gmail like web mail provider. Some of your users are using a third party app which logs in into your user's account and auto replies certain emails for you. Or you are Facebook like social network web site where some of your users use a third party app which analyzes your friend networks and prints a 2D graph for you. In this case your users are giving away their usernames and passwords. How would they prevent a certain third party app accessing their account after they gave away their username and password? Simply by changing their password. Now you have another problem; other third party apps won't be able to access the user's account. Then the user have to re-give away his password to other apps he trusts. Now this is problem too because it is not user friendly. OAuth is simply a temporary password that your user gives away to a third party app developer. He can revoke it whenever he wants without changing his own password.

Other than that OAuth is unnecessary. Just use a session cookie if you are not going to have third party app developers. It is a random string stored in user side. And on the server side will have whatever you want. Just look how PHP sessions are used and stored on server side. You can define their lifespan and refresh time automatically from php.ini.